# Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens - kafka spring integration demo application

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-integration, apache-kafka

I am trying to use the [demo application](https://github.com/joshlong/spring-and-kafka) for spring kafka integration and getting an "syntax error on token, delete these token" error in eclipse. looks to be simple one, but i dont know how to fix.

errors at **return args ->**

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("kafkaOutboundChannelAdapter")
CommandLineRunner kickOff(@Qualifier("inputToKafka") MessageChannel in) {
    return args -> {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            in.send(new GenericMessage<>("#" + i));
            log.info("sending message #" + i);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does your version of Eclipse support Java 8 syntax? Is your project configured to allow it?

Comment: I am using "Kepler Service Release 2" eclipse [version: 4.3.2]. I have jdk 1.8 installed and project JRE library points to 1.8. Anything else i have to do?

Comment: Possibly. https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler Or upgrade to  `Luna`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Java 8 syntax, but Kepler SR2 itself doesn't support Java 8 syntax without the patches discussed here: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler . Luna officially supports Java 8.